# For what $\alpha$ does the series converge: $\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac {1}{n^\alpha\log_2(n)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Let $\alpha\ge 0$ check for what $\alpha$ does the series converge: $$\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=2}\dfrac {1}{n^\alpha\log_2(n)}$$

I tried the condensation test and get: $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1}\dfrac {1}{(n+1)2^{\alpha n}}$ but here it would converge for $\alpha\ge 1$ which doesn't seem right at all (the original series looks like it would converge for $\alpha>1$, so trying to compare: $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=2}\dfrac {1}{n^\alpha\log_2(n)}\le \sum^\infty_{n=1}\dfrac {1}{n^\alpha}$ clearly, the series converge for $\alpha>1$.

Note: no integrals.

Comment: It doesn't converge for $\alpha = 1$. Try integral test.

Comment: @user121270 I can't use integrals.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the factor $2^n$ in the condensation, you should get $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n2^{\alpha n}} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^{(\alpha-1)n}}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer, isn't that $\large\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n2^{\alpha(n-1)}}$ ? then I just shifted the index. Edit: oh ok I see now I didn't 'simplify' it correctly.

Comment: No, $$\frac{2^n}{2^{\alpha n}} = \frac{1}{2^{(\alpha n) - n}} = \frac{1}{2^{(\alpha-1)n}} \neq \frac{1}{2^{\alpha(n-1)}}.$$ $\alpha (n-1) = \alpha n - n$. In the correct form, you see that the condensed series converges iff $\alpha-1 > 0$.

Comment: If you know Lagrange theorem you can use this. $$ln(ln(n+1))-ln(ln(n))=\frac{1}{(n+\theta)ln(n+\theta)}\ge\frac{1}{nln(n)}$$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Condensation Test gives
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n}{n\,2^{\alpha n}}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n\,2^{(\alpha-1)n}}\tag{1}
$$
which converges by comparison to a geometric series for $\alpha\gt1$. For $\alpha=1$, $(1)$ is the harmonic series,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1n\tag{2}
$$
to which we can again apply the Condensation Test to get
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2^n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty1\tag{3}
$$
which clearly diverges.

Thus, the original series converges if and only if $\alpha\gt1$.

Comment: Isn't it enough to just use comparison test for $\alpha>1$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed the "no integrals" request.  Comparison is okay if you are given that $\sum\frac1{n^\alpha}$ converges for $\alpha\gt1$; however, you need to show divergence for $\alpha=1$. I will modify my answer to not use integrals.